# Difference between Date in Decimal Format

Tags: c++, datetime, decimal

I have a text file stating the Date as follows:

```
40097.586458333 - Number of days that have passed since 12/30/1899.
```

How can we convert it to human-readable date-time using C++?
I am interested in calculating the difference (in seconds) between two dates, i.e., 40097.5865162037 - 40097.586458333,

Comment: c++11 has a chrono class

Comment: Assuming the fractional part really is a fraction of the day, surely it's just `86400 * (t1 - t2)` ?

Comment: @Botje Yes, it is! Thanks a lot! :)
If you post it as an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function convert second into day, hours, minutes and seconds 
I hope this help you.

```
void ConvertSectoDay(int n) { 
 int day = n / (24 * 3600); 

 n = n % (24 * 3600); 
 int hour = n / 3600; 

 n %= 3600; 
 int minutes = n / 60 ; 

 n %= 60; 
 int seconds = n; 

 cout << day << " " << "days " << hour  
     << " " << "hours " << minutes << " " 
     << "minutes " << seconds << " " 
     << "seconds "  << endl; 
}
```

source [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/converting-seconds-into-days-hours-minutes-and-seconds/)